# Cannot Boot Ubuntu 12.10 (No wubildr / Cannot find GRLDR)

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, wubi

I'm new to using Ubuntu and installed it using Wubi.exe on Windows 8. I created the partition, booted Ubuntu and everything was fine. I shutdown my laptop for the night and when I attempted to boot Ubuntu i got this screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLWFB.jpg

I've searched the forums and found one answer saying to copy "all 3" wubildr files into c\, which I see only two (wubildr and wubilder.mbr). Also my grub folder is empty, there are no hidden files in it what-so-ever. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

It's the `wubildr` file it cannot find. It looks on all partitions until it finds one. So, maybe it has a problem finding it on `C:` (for whatever reason). Just copy it *to the root* of another drive. e.g. `D:\wubildr`. It doesn't matter which drive.

Comment: btw bcbc, do you know if WUBI works with Windows 8? I've heard that it doesn't, but you seem to be saying it does.. Is it just one of the new Win 8 features that stops it? (secure boot, etc)

Comment: @Seth it works with Windows 8. It doesn't work with GPT formatted disks because `grub4dos` doesn't work (so this rules out preinstalled Windows8 computers because they all have GPT disks). It would also fail with secure boot because the wubildr.mbr is unsigned, but it wouldn't work anyway because of the above problem. You can actually make Wubi work on even a secure boot system, but only through a lot of manual tweaking (it's been done, not by me).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, you cannot install OS within windows and run it. Create Bootable USB (Easier than CD), you can go to http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ to create bootable disk. You can save ISO image from http://www.ubuntu.com first and then create bootable using the ISO image.Boot from the USB and you are good to go.